# CSS text with border to the right

Tags: html, css, grid

I need help to make a vertical line between the paragraph name, street, postal, email, orgnr. I understand that I need to make a `border-right` and maybe create divs to get the right margins.

I want to keep the same behaviour I have now on the css but don't know how. I tried with the divs but it didn't look good.

```css
.footer_contact {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-top: 79px;
}

.footer_contact p {
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.050em;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-right: 35px;
}

.footer_contact ul {
 font-size: 12px;
 list-style: none;

}

.footer_contact ul li {
 float: right;
}

.footer_contact a {
 color: #3c273a;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 77px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer_contact">
    <div class="grid_medium_footer">
        <nav class="footer_icons">
            <ul class="social_icons">
                <li><a href="#" class="social_instagram">Instragram<i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="social_facebook">Facebook<i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="social_linkedin">Linkedin<i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="social_twitter">Twitter<i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav> 
        <p>Name</p>
        <p>Street</p>
        <p>Postal</p>
        <p>Email</p><br>
        <p>Orgnr</p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- grid_medium_footer -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some changes in your code hope this will help

```css
.footer_contact {
 
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-top: 79px;
}


.footer_contact p {
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.050em;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: 500;
 width:100px;
 text-align: center;
}


.footer_contact ul {
 font-size: 12px;
 list-style: none;
 
}

.footer_contact ul li {
    float: left;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer_contact ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
.footer_contact a {
    color: #3c273a;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="footer_contact">
  <div class="grid_medium_footer">
   
    <nav class="footer_icons">
               <ul class="social_icons">
                 <li><a href="#" class="social_instagram">Instragram<i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" class="social_facebook">Facebook<i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" class="social_linkedin">Linkedin<i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" class="social_twitter">Twitter<i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
               </ul>
         </nav> 
      <div>          
   
      <p>Name</p>
      <p>Street</p>
      <p>Postal</p>
      <p>Email</p><br>
      <p>Orgnr</p>
    </div>
    </div>   
   
  
 </div> <!-- grid_medium_footer -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? Otherwise, please be more specific.

```css
.footer_contact p {
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 0.050em;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: This should be enough. Concretely, setting `display`, `margin-right`, `padding-right` and `border-right` properties like this is enough.

Comment: Might also want to use `.footer_contact p:last-child` to unset the border for the last element :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.footer_contact p{
    display:inline;
    padding: 0 2%;
    line-height: 2em;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-right: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 0.050em;
}
```

Comment: Although the code might solve the problem, a good answer should always contain an explanation.